# are routers in django Restframework necessary to use?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

i have a stupid question about routers in DRF. so when i set url patters correctly and url endpoints are directing me to specific object.is this necessary to use routers?I am confused about this topic.better question:
what is routers and why we should use it?

Comment: You can do fine without routers. They remove some burden to generate urls but only work with view sets.

Comment: this means that no forcing to use routers.tnx @Linovia